# Subsetting data frame based on different replicate names in a column and dynamically naming subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame like this:

```
> head(ratData)
  Chromosome Start_Gene startPosition End_gene endPosition RNAtype strand           replicate
1      chr20        C4b       6382078      C4b     6381944     reg      - Thymus_M_GSM1328751
2       chr8       Rpl4      68832532     Rpl4    68832743     reg      + Thymus_M_GSM1328751
3       chr1       Dntt     267744370     Dntt   267746423     reg      + Thymus_M_GSM1328751
4      chr14     Sptbn1     114201107   Sptbn1   114200202     reg      - Thymus_M_GSM1328751
5      chr19     Ndufb7      35680273   Ndufb7    35683909     reg      + Thymus_M_GSM1328751
6      chr10    Ndufb10      13906408  Ndufb10    13906289     reg      - Thymus_M_GSM1328751
```

Now the actual data file is huge and there are around ~50-80 replicates. Now what I want to do is for each replicate "a" make a subset data frame named "a". So, if in the column replicate, we have "a", "b", "c" etc, I would like to make subset data frames of names "a", "b", "c" etc. Ideally, I would like to make a list/map of this subsetted data frames.

I have similar data file for human, and the end goal is to use for loop to compare each replicate of human with each replicate of rat. I am new to **R** and am totally confused how I can do it. I am thinking of using some sort of map/dictionary system as in C++/python. But not sure if it's the right way to deal with it.

Any insight/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `lst <- split(ratData, ratData$replicate)` and similarly for human dataset.  But without any expected output and example dataset from human dataset, it is hard to provide a solution.

Comment: if you want to compare the human/rat replicates maybe a good solution for the analysis and graphs is to rowbind the two dataframes and create a categorical variable with values "rat" or "human". After that you might split your data (akrun's comment)